# How to use Meilisearch filters in Laravel lighthouse @search

Tags: laravel-lighthouse, laravel-scout, meilisearch

How can I use [meilisearch filters](https://www.meilisearch.com/docs/learn/fine_tuning_results/filtering#using-filters) in laravel lighthouse [@search directive](https://lighthouse-php.com/master/api-reference/directives.html#search)

I have for example:

```
type Query {
  movies(search: String @search): [Movie!]! @paginate
}
```

I tried a graphql query with search as a variable but it doesn't work:

```
 {
   "search": "'Avengers', ['filter' => 'release_date > 795484800']"
 }
```

Eveything is set up correctly in scout because if I use curl with the example from meilisearch docs everything works correctly!
But I cannot figure out how to add filter value to the @search directive in lighthouse.

```
curl \
  -X POST 'http://localhost:7700/indexes/movie_ratings/search' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data-binary '{
    "q": "Avengers",
    "filter": "release_date > 795484800"
  }'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all [laravel 10.x scout only supports where clauses with `=`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/scout#where-clauses) not with `<` or `>`

So for the example above I ended up using a local scope that returns a Boolean and I added it to `toSearchableArray()`.

If everything is setup correctly in scout's meilisearch settings (you added `filterableAttributes` in the `index-settings`) you may use that filter in a where clause inside scout builder.

So the query in lighthouse looks like this:

```
type Query {
  movies(search: String @search released: Boolean @released): [Movie!]! @paginate
}
```

Where `@released` is a custom directive (arg builder) that implements `ScoutBuilderDirective` that adds to the scout builder:

```
public function handleScoutBuilder(ScoutBuilder $builder, mixed $value): ScoutBuilder
    {
        return $builder->where('released', true);
    }
```